# Send Array from ViewHelper to the Fluidtemplate and printout

Tags: php, arrays, fluid, extbase, viewhelper

I'm working with Typo3, extbase and fluid. I will get an array (multidimensional associative Array) from a php file into my fluid template and print it out there with a loop.
I already have a own ViewHelper but I dont know how to send it to the template. They write something about the "controller" where you can initialize these variables but I don't understand it.

If there is another (simpler) way, please let me know it

Answer (score 0):

In your controller action, you can assign variables to your view with

```
public function listAction() {
    // ...
    $this->view->assign('yourArrayInFluid', $yourArray);
}
```

But what do you need a viewhelper for? You can traverse through arrays in fluid with the already available viewhelpers, for example:

```
<f:for each="{yourArrayInFluid}" as="yourValue" key="yourKey">
    <p>{yourValue}</p>
</f:for>
```

You can nest these viewhelpers, so multidimensional arrays should be no problem they aren't dynamic or too complex.

(As seen in the [fluid documentation](http://wiki.typo3.org/Fluid#f:for))

Comment: thank you for your answer. I assigned variables with the assign command. I don't know what was the problem but now it it works fine.